# using result from a stored procedure with parameters as value for gauge chart - crystal reports in asp.net application

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a stored procedure that takes in 2 parameters and returns an integer value. I would like this value to be the value for a gauge chart on the page. The 2 parameters will change depending on the attributes of the selected item. Is there a simple way to pass the one value from the stored procedure to the chart to display? This will be embedded in an asp.net application (vb) - so depending on the previously selected item, the values for the parameters and result will change. thank you for your help.

Comment: Are there other tables in the report or do you *just* want to display the chart?

Comment: just display the chart- the page this will go on will be displayed in an iframe of another page, so just the chart.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the package

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE REPORTING AS

   type query_results is ref cursor;

   PROCEDURE barfoo (one IN INTEGER, two IN INTEGER, three IN OUT REPORTING.query_results);
   ```

   END REPORTING;
2. Create the stored procedure

   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BARFOO ( 
      one IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
      two IN INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
      three IN OUT reporting.query_results
    ) AS
    BEGIN

   open three for
      select  one + two total
      from    dual
      ;

   END BARFOO;
3. Build the report

3a. Ensure that stored procedures will be visible in the Database 'Expert'

[image]

3b. Add the stored procedure to the report

[image]

3c. Add Chart

Insert | Chart... | Type tab | Gauge, then Data tab

[image]

4. The result

[image]

Comment: the values of the 2 variables passed to the stored procedures will be changing based on which items are selected, so I'm more so looking for how to do this in visual studio 2010 - to change the value of the two variables for the item selected.