# Update Reports to filter with an Oracle function in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have several reports, and on each one of them i have a few tables included.

Lets say 3 tables, tableA, tableB and tableC.
I want to use the following Oracle Function to filter the result set passing also a report parameter:

```
AND function(tableB.field1, tableB.field2, tableB.field3, {?report_parameter}) = 'S'
```

Facts to be aware of:

- Oracle Functions can only be used on SQL Expressions and/or SQL Commands in Crystal Reports.
- SQL Expressions cannot contain report parameters (so, not an option).
- Crystal Reports lets you replace a report table with a SQL Command, but does not let you replace several tables to a single SQL Command.
- We do not want to re-build all the reports all over again.
- We do not want to replace a single table to a SQL Command because it affects performance in a high level since Crystal does not transform the tables and the SQL Command on a single query when executing the report.
- This Oracle Function selects data from other tables and therefore can not be rewritten on a Report Custom Function.
- The {?report_parameter} is an information that only the application knows. It is filled by the application before exporting the report to the user.

What could I do to work around this?

Comment: Are you trying to 'burst' the report?

Comment: "Report Bursting is nothing but running the report at one time and distributing the results to multiple users". If that's what you mean, then no.

Comment: Run once, distribute many, where each recipient gets a personalized copy of the report.  This is easily done by manipulating the record-selection formula.

Answer (score 0):

No knowing exactly why your function requires tables and parameter, I can only give you vague, untested options.  None of the options are ideal:

- rewrite your Oracle function as 'Custom Function' (CF); reference CF in record-selection formula; filter will be applied WhileReadingRecords (i.e. the function will not be sent to the database)
- rewrite your function as a stored procedure that accepts one parameter, but returns a record set (the parameter will be recognized by Crystal Reports); join the other tables to the stored procedure.  The stored procedure will need to be written in a manner that will support Crystal Reports' data needs ([using result from a stored procedure with parameters as value for gauge chart - crystal reports in asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953789/using-result-from-a-stored-procedure-with-parameters-as-value-for-gauge-chart/10984207#10984207))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The report parameter is an information that only the application knows. The parameter is filled by the application before exporting the report. I'll Check the stored procedure thing.

Comment: Tried to add a simple stored procedure to one of the reports, it looks like crystal does not identify the ref cursor parameter. I defined it with a number parameter (IN) and the ref cursor parameter (IN OUT). When I tried to add it to the report, crystal showed the param prompt with the number parameter only, after clicking 'OK', it gives the error: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XYZ'. We use the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider, that could be the reason.

Comment: Yes, the provider seems to be the problem (http://forums.asp.net/t/1736628.aspx/1). Additionally, about the custom function option, can it access the database somehow? Because the Oracle Function is totally based on other tables data.

Comment: No, a custom function can only operate on the values that are passed to it.

Comment: Too bad it isn't an option either. Thanks tho.