# Getting the sum of columns based on row values

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, pivot

I have a table that looks like the following.

```
EMPNUM  EMPNAME     LOCATION    CATEGORY    COUNT
123     JOHN DOE    BLDG A      1           5
123     JOHN DOE    BLDG A      1           6
123     JOHN DOE    BLDG A      2           4
123     JOHN DOE    BLDG A      3           7
123     JOHN DOE    BLDG B      1           1
123     JOHN DOE    BLDG B      2           3
234     EMILY DOE   BLDG A      1           1
234     EMILY DOE   BLDG A      2           2
234     EMILY DOE   BLDG A      3           4
234     EMILY DOE   BLDG B      2           3
234     EMILY DOE   BLDG B      2           9
234     EMILY DOE   BLDG B      3           3
```

I would like to transport it into columns that will yield to an output similar to below. I need to get the sum of COUNT based on the values of LOCATION and CATEGORY

```
EMPNUM  EMPNAME     SUM_A1  SUM_A2  SUM_A3  SUM_B1  SUM_B2  SUM_B3  
123     JOHN DOE    11      4       7       1       3       0
234     EMILY DOE   1       2       4       0       12      3
```

Is there any way to do this as an SQL query? or in Crystal reports (though I prefer output using SQL)

Comment: Are the values for LOCATION and CATEGORY constant ? I mean do you know that the results will have only these 8 columns ?

Answer (score 3):

This will work providing the values in LOCATION and CATEGORY are constant:

```
select empnum
       , empname
       , sum(case when location='BLDG A' and category = 1 then count else 0 end) sum_a1 
       , sum(case when location='BLDG A' and category = 2 then count else 0 end) sum_a2
       , sum(case when location='BLDG A' and category = 3 then count else 0 end) sum_a3
       , sum(case when location='BLDG B' and category = 1 then count else 0 end) sum_b1
       , sum(case when location='BLDG B' and category = 2 then count else 0 end) sum_b2
       , sum(case when location='BLDG B' and category = 3 then count else 0 end) sum_b3
from your_table
group by empnum
       , empname
```

If the values are not known or not stable when you run the query you will need to use dynamic SQL.

---

Note that if you are on 11g you should employ [A B Cade's PIVOT solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13082873/146325), which is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using 11g or later try

```
select * from table1
PIVOT  (SUM("COUNT")         
        FOR ("LOCATION","CATEGORY") IN 
        (('BLDG A',1) AS sum_a1,
         ('BLDG A',2) AS sum_a2,
         ('BLDG A',3) AS sum_a3,
        ('BLDG B',1) AS sum_b1,
        ('BLDG B',2) AS sum_b2,
        ('BLDG B',3) AS sum_b3));
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1905/18) is a fiddle

Otherwise use [APC's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13082852/1083652)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work great if you have a known number of values to transform into columns. But if you have an unknown number, then you can use dynamic sql to generate the results.

You would create the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure test_dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select empnum, empname';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct location, category from yourtable order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
              ' , sum(case when location = '''||x.location||''' and category='||x.category||' then cnt else 0 end) as sum_'||substr(x.location, -1, 1)||x.category;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from yourtable group by empnum, empname';

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

And then to execute it:

```
variable x refcursor
exec test_dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x
```

The result is the same as the hard-coded version:

```
| EMPNUM |   EMPNAME | SUM_A1 | SUM_A2 | SUM_A3 | SUM_B1 | SUM_B2 | SUM_B3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    234 | EMILY DOE |      1 |      2 |      4 |      0 |     12 |      3 |
|    123 |  JOHN DOE |     11 |      4 |      7 |      1 |      3 |      0 |
```

Comment: +1: technique (dynamic SQL)
-1: solution won't work in Crystal Reports; it needs to have an `IN OUT` parameter that returns a `REF CURSOR` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953789/using-result-from-a-stored-procedure-with-parameters-as-value-for-gauge-chart/10984207#10984207)
-1: stored procedures are *nearly always* over-kill when used for reporting purpose

Comment: @craig I am providing an alternate solution for a dynamic pivot, I am not saying it is the best but for dynamic sql in oracle there is no other way.

Comment: @craig and this answer is in fact not wrong and does not warrant a downvote.